# I am getting undefined error in labels whenever I am trying to access list of label in gmail API

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

```
function listLabels(userId, callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({   
        'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        var labels = resp.labels;                 
        console.log(labels);                      
        // callback(labels)
    });
}
```

The request object accessed is made for labels but when labels is logged it returns `undefined`.

Comment: There is no issue with the part of the code you posted for labels.list. Can you try same request https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list here. If request succeed here, it could be problem with the code. If you still see issue, please post your response details.

Comment: Also check this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js gmail api client in java script